# DeviceLostException during CTRL ALT DEL in Direct3D using C#

Tags: c#, exception, windows-xp, directx, direct3d

I am using the Microsoft.DirectX and Microsoft.DirectX.Direct3D references to do some drawing on my form. While I am running the program and the user presses CTRL ALT DEL in Windows XP and brings up the "Windows Security" form, when returning back to the Form, a DeviceLostException is thrown and when trying to handle this exception there seems to be no way to get it back.

I have done a little research into the matter and have tried several coding solutions.

```
        try
        {
             _d3ddevice.Present();                 
        }
        catch 
        {
            DeviceLost = true;
        }

        if (DeviceLost) 
        {
            AttemptRecovery();
        }

        this.Invalidate();
        ReadKeyboard();

        base.OnPaint(e);          

    }    

    private void AttemptRecovery()
    {
        try
        {
            _d3ddevice.TestCooperativeLevel();
        }
        catch (DeviceLostException)
        {
            Application.Exit();
        }
        catch (DeviceNotResetException)
        {
            try
            {
                _d3ddevice.Reset(_params);
                DeviceLost = false;

                InitGraphics();
                CameraPositioning();
                VertexDeclaration();
                IndicesDeclaration();         
            }
            catch (DeviceLostException)
            {
            }
        }
    }
```

When the program calls TestCooperativeLevel(), it said online if it catches the DeviceLostException again that there is no point in trying to reset the device.

What can I do to reset the device and continue drawing in my form?

Comment: This behaviour is documented. There are several reasons for loosing the device, and you'll have to wait until you can create a new one. This is the main reason for so many games (historically) used to crash when you switched out of the game (alt-tab, alt-enter, ctrl-alt-del, popups, etc).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

2 things in 4 points :

- You shouldn't use Microsoft.DirectX, it's deprecated since a long, long time. Check out SlimDX or SharpDX instead.
- In order to re-create your device, you first have to *wait* until the device can be restored
- When the device can be restored, you have to free all video-memory objects, and recreate them.
- You call the `Reset` method.